# Rails creating object with the wrong id for certain field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a mentions system similar to the one in twitter. So I am dealing with three classes in this problem: Post, User and Mention. The mention object has a mentioned_id field (the mentioned user) and a post_id ( the post in which it happens).
I found some weird problems while writing tests, so I opened a console session, and this is what happens:
I create two users, two posts, and two mentions. If you notice, when I create the second mention (@mention2) the id of @mentioned_id is not the correct user's id:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > @user1 = Factory(:user, :email => Factory.next(:email))

 => #<User id: 1, name: "Fulano", email: "person_number1@example.com", created_at: "2011-09-11 15:38:11", updated_at: "2011-09-11 15:38:11", encrypted_password: "ede4e8cc0440b8bd9fdc059e8496154715b6592690157aac618...", salt: "4bfae8fecee1629b7c290c2d5af5bd3bbeb38c4ce76546d7176...", admin: false> 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > @user2 = Factory(:user, :email => Factory.next(:email))

 => #<User id: 2, name: "Fulano", email: "person_number2@example.com", created_at: "2011-09-11 15:39:06", updated_at: "2011-09-11 15:39:06", encrypted_password: "ddda10f48575f63724e1db3d3cf684f2c60380325236311e15d...", salt: "911121b8942dc57116dfd24383d96874c750bc5a21fa210288b...", admin: false> 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > @post1 = Factory(:post, :user => @user1)

 => #<post id: 1, content: "Foo bar", user_id: 1, created_at: "2011-09-11 15:39:57", updated_at: "2011-09-11 15:39:57"> 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > @post2 = Factory(:post, :user => @user2)

 => #<post id: 2, content: "Foo bar", user_id: 2, created_at: "2011-09-11 15:40:37", updated_at: "2011-09-11 15:40:37"> 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005 > @mention1 = @post2.mentions.create :mentioned_id => @user1

 => #<Mention id: 1, post_id: 2, mentioned_id: 1, created_at: "2011-09-11 15:41:33", updated_at: "2011-09-11 15:41:33"> 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007 > @mention2 = @post1.mentions.create :mentioned_id => @user2

 => #<Mention id: 2, post_id: 1, mentioned_id: 1, created_at: "2011-09-11 15:42:16", updated_at: "2011-09-11 15:42:16">
```

Strangely enough, if I use **@user2.id** instead of just @user2 that last line, everything works fine:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :008 > @mention2 = @post1.mentions.create :mentioned_id => @user2.id


=> #<Mention id: 3, post_id: 1, mentioned_id: 2, created_at: "2011-09-11 15:45:16", updated_at: "2011-09-11 15:45:16">
```

Can anyone please tell me what's happening? I thought rails "magic" took care of getting the id when referencing an object. And why would it work with the first user but not with the second??

This is the code for my mention class:

```
class Mention < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :mentioned_id

  belongs_to :mentioned, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :post

  validates :mentioned, :presence => true
  validates :post, :presence => true

end
```

And this is the relevant portion of the code for my user class:

```
    Class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  …

  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy  
  has_many :mentions, :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_key => 'mentioned_id'

  …
```

This also happens in my spec test:

```
 @user = Factory(:user, :email => Factory.next(:email))
  @other_user = Factory(:user, :email => Factory.next(:email))

  @post1 = Factory(:post, :user => @other_user)
  @post2 = Factory(:post, :user => @other_user)
  @post3 = Factory(:post, :user => @user) 
  @mention1 = @post1.mentions.create :mentioned_id => @user
  @mention2 = @post2.mentions.create :mentioned_id => @user 
  @mention3 = @post3.mentions.create :mentioned_id => @other_user.id
```

The last line only works correctly if I use the .id method, but the previous two work correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to ask Rails to map an integer (`mentioned_id`) to an object (`@user`). You're doing it correctly on your `@post1 = ...` lines, where you're assigning `@other_user` to `:user`, not `:user_id`. You need to do the same on your `@mention1 = ...` lines:

```
@mention1 = @post1.mentions.create :mentioned => @user
```

However, with your code as it is, this won't work either, because your `attr_accessor` line is interfering.

You can either get rid of the line altogether and the `:mentioned => @user` part will work, or you can change it like so, to allow assigning directly to `:mentioned` rather than `:mentioned_id` (yes, they really are the same thing, but it seems that Rails checks `attr_accessible` and denies access to updating `:mentioned` before it realizes that `:mentioned` is really just `:mentioned_id` anyway).

```
attr_accessible :mentioned_id, :mentioned
```

Comment: I tried that before, and it doesnt seem to work. If I do that, the mention's mentioned_id field is set to nil, for some reason

Comment: ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005 > p.mentions.create :mentioned => user1
 => #<Mention id: nil, post_id: 1, mentioned_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Comment: When you do your `p.mentions.create :mentioned => user1` entry in the console, you are probably seeing "WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: mentioned". This is because of your `attr_accessible :mentioned_id` line in your `Mention` model. Get rid of it and it'll work.

Comment: This works, you should edit your reply and add this, so I can mark it as accepted. Thank you man. I think I still dont fully get what attr_accessible does, but I read that it is necessary to define attr_accessible for security reasons. Wouldn't remove it make every attribute editable through mass assignment?

Comment: I did edit the reply earlier, see the last line. If you have a model where you don't want to let the user modify certain fields, then you would want to use `attr_accessible` to make sure they can only modify the fields you want.  I'll edit my answer again to show how this could work for you.